# Jpanel click creates event

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouse-listeners

I am making a connect four game in Java. I got the 6*7 layout and the sound components working. What I am trying to do is have hollow circles, when you click a hollow circle it fills with the player's colour and can't be clicked again. I am not sure how to trigger an event in such a specific area. Any hints or suggestions welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about MouseMotionListener, MouseListener. You are able to get mouse coordinates and you are able to know if user clicked the mouse. When user clik in a specyfic area for example (x>20, x<30, y>20, y<40) use paintComponent method to draw a circle with specyfic color.